# Return set of unique values from multiple rows of arrays in sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables, one called Tasks and another called TaskUpdates (one to many relation). TaskUpdates has a column called tags, which is an array. I am trying to get back an array that has only unique values from the TaskUpdates.tags

```
class Task(BASE):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # One Task to Many Updates
    updates = relationship("TaskUpdate")


class TaskUpdate(BASE):
    __tablename__ = 'task_updates'

    # Columns
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = Column(ARRAY(String(255)))
    task_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tasks.id'))
    task = relationship('Task', back_populates="updates")
```

Comment: so, what the problem?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Wrap your list in a `set()`. Or redesign your array column to a tags table with a many to many relation with taskupdate. etc.